# Improve performance of VBA code about splitting strings

Tags: excel, vba, string

I need to do the following:

I have a table where the 13th column contains strings such as

```
acbd,ef,xyz
qwe,rtyu,tqyuiop
```

And what I want to create new rows in order to separate those values:

```
acbd
ef
xyz
qwe
rtyu
tqyuiop
```

Meaning I would have now 6 rows instead of 2, and all the other information on cells would remain the same (i.e. all the other values of the row would repeat themselves through all the new rows).

What I have tried is the following:

```
Sub test()

Dim coma As Integer
Dim finalString As String

Set sh = ActiveSheet
For Each rw In sh.Rows

* If find a coma, then copy the row, insert a new row, and paste in this new row*

If InStr(1, sh.Cells(rw.Row, 13).Value, ",") Then

Rows(rw.Row).Copy
Rows(rw.Row).insert shift:=xlShiftDown
Rows(rw.Row).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

* Now it will look for the position of the comma and assign 
  to finalString what's before the comma, and assign to mod String
  what's after the comma *

coma = InStr(1, sh.Cells(rw.Row, 13).Value, ",")

finalString = Left(sh.Cells(rw.Row, 13).Value, coma - 1)
modString = Right(sh.Cells(rw.Row, 13).Value, Len(sh.Cells(rw.Row, 13).Value) - coma)

* Replace the values: *

sh.Cells(rw.Row, 13).Value = modString
sh.Cells(rw.Row - 1, 13).Value = finalString

End If

Next rw

MsgBox ("End")

End Sub
```

This code works perfectly well except that for tables with 400 rows it takes 15 +-5 seconds to be completed.

I would like some suggestions on how to improve the performance of this. Thank you!

Comment: Read your Usedrange into an array, do the spltting and copying there, place result back to your sheet

Comment: And use `Split` rather than repeated searching and parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vR(), vS, s
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer, n As Long

    vDB = Range("a1").CurrentRegion

    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        vS = Split(vDB(i, 13), ",")
        For Each s In vS
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 13, 1 To n)
            For j = 1 To 12
                vR(j, n) = vDB(i, j)
            Next j
            vR(13, n) = s
        Next s
    Next i
    Range("a1").Resize(n, 13) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)

End Sub
```

Before.

[image]

After.

[image]

If you have more columns, do like this.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vR(), vS, s
    Dim i As Long, j As Integer, n As Long
    Dim c As Integer

    vDB = Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)

    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        vS = Split(vDB(i, 13), ",")
        For Each s In vS
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To c, 1 To n)
            For j = 1 To c
                vR(j, n) = vDB(i, j)
            Next j
            vR(13, n) = s
        Next s
    Next i
    Range("a1").Resize(n, c) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. One more thing, what if I wanted to preserve also what is next to column 13? I mean, columns 14,15,16... (I have 19 columns)

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked much more quickly than mine.

Answer (score 4):

With data in column **L**, give this a try:

```
Sub LongList()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction, arr, s As String

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    s = wf.TextJoin(",", True, Range("L:L"))
    arr = Split(s, ",")
    Range("M1").Resize(UBound(arr) + 1, 1).Value = wf.Transpose(arr)
End Sub
```

[image]

Note:

No looping over cells.
No looping within cells.
 This process can be accomplished with just worksheet formulas, VBA is not needed.

Comment: I know that what you said is possible without VBA. What I mean is, columns A to K are also full of information and so, for example, take row 5, with data in columns A,..,K and in M "abc,ef,xyz". I want to create rows, one with the data from A to K and "abc" in M, another one with the data (repeated) from A to K and "ef" in column M, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an immediate boost in performance without having to adjust any kind of code just add Application events at the beginning...

```
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With
```

and be sure to turn them back on at the end of the code...

```
With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

These two simple statements usually speed up code considerably.

Answer (score 1):

This should look for comma-delimited values in column M and overwrite the values in column M with the split values (basically what your code was doing).

```
Option Explicit

Sub splitValues()

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet

    With sourceSheet
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

        Dim inputValues() As Variant
        inputValues = .Range("M1:M" & lastRow).Value2

        Dim splitString() As String
        Dim rowIndex As Long
        Dim outputArray As Variant
        Dim outputRowIndex As Long
        outputRowIndex = 1

        For rowIndex = LBound(inputValues, 1) To UBound(inputValues, 1)
            splitString = VBA.Strings.Split(inputValues(rowIndex, 1), ",", -1, vbBinaryCompare)
            outputArray = Application.Transpose(splitString)
            .Cells(outputRowIndex, "M").Resize(UBound(outputArray, 1), UBound(outputArray, 2)).Value2 = outputArray
            outputRowIndex = outputRowIndex + UBound(outputArray, 1)
        Next rowIndex

    End With

End Sub
```